# Where to get "/etc/ld.so.nohwcap" file from?

Tags: debugging, dynamic-linking, system-calls, strace, ld

When I run a command through `strace` utility I can see access errors such as

`access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Now I've read somewhere that what's happening on the above line is that a linker is looking for optimized version of the command that I'm running but can't find it.

How do I solve this problem ? What package do I need to install so that I can have that `ld.so.nohwcap` file on the system ? Even if not for optimization purposes but just to get rid of these errors in `strace` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably don’t want to “solve” this problem; according to [the Debian `glibc` manpage for `ld.so`](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/-/blob/e7ad831c16a15103827d1013e59739ac1fbe24bb/debian/local/manpages/ld.so.8),

> **`/etc/ld.so.nohwcap`** When this file is present the dynamic  linker  will  load  the  non-optimized  version  of  a library, even if the CPU supports the optimized version.

It’s not installed by a package, it can be created by the system administrator to *disable* loading optimised libraries.

Note that this is Debian-specific: the feature is implemented by a [patch](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/-/blob/sid/debian/patches/any/local-ldso-disable-hwcap.diff) in the Debian `glibc` package, and isn’t available in upstream `glibc`. The feature’s documentation disappeared from the `ld.so` manpage when the latter was moved from `glibc` to the [`man-pages` project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/).

Comment: Why would you want to load a non-optimized version of a library though ?

Comment: The Debian patch explains why this is useful: Debian supports in-place glibc upgrades, and disabling hwcap libraries makes this easier for some reason I haven't figured out (perhaps to avoid having mis-matched versions of libraries being used).